# Stalled Hosted Agent VSTS

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I seemed to have stalled my hosted agent in VSTS.  Any ideas on how to clear and restart it?[image: VSTS Dashboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have much control over the hosted agent. You can always cancel the builds or let those expire which should provoke a re provision of the allocated agent.